# Listening for a slash keystroke without knowing the modifier key in Swing

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, keystroke

I am trying to listen to the keystroke for a slash character in a Swing component.
Registering it with

```
component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH, 0), myAction);
```

works, when using an english keyboard layout (where a slash is a single keystroke). However when using a german keyboard layout, a slash is entered via shift-7 and the obove code doesn't work!

Now what is the correct way to listen for exactly a slash character, instead of a combination of key?

Comment: I'd make it a user [preference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/package-summary.html) or handle it as part of [Internationalization](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/intl-139810.html).

Comment: @trashgod I am sorry, but I dont't see how this helps?

Comment: Anything defined with a KeyEvent.VK does listen for that very specific *key* on the keyboard, completely independent on what character that key actually produces with the current key layout. Try getKeyStroke(char) and variants. These work with the actual key map.

Comment: @radlan: Allow the user to reassign key bindings; save the result in `Preferences`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current KeyStroke listens for the keyPressed event.

Maybe you can use:

```
KeyStroke slash = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("typed /");  // or
KeyStroke slash = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('/');
```

This should listen for the keyTyped event which should work for KeyStrokes that actually generated a typed character that can be added to a text field for example.

Comment: Thanks! That really did it! I didn't know of the possibility of specifiying "typed /".